# Help identify this IR receiver

Tags: identification, infrared, phototransistor, photosensor

This part came out of a Logitech nanoVX mouse. It is the IR sensor that is  part of the scroll wheel mechanism.

It has letters LT written on top and on the back it seems to have "H0fVE" or "HOfVE" or "HllfVE" engraved. Can anyone identify it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: LT might stand for "Linear Technology" - a major component manufacturer. If you don't have any luck here, you might try asking them..

Comment: Most likely a dual phototransistor https://cdn.instructables.com/FF0/I8O3/HPZLKCQW/FF0I8O3HPZLKCQW.LARGE.jpg

Comment: Linear Tech doesn't make opto's

Comment: That second character looks like it might be a stencil font "8" I get no hits on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differential PT's used in high volume may be hard to find.

I suggest this replacement in stock. PT2559B/L2-F

$0.71 (1) http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/everlight-electronics-co-ltd/PT2559B-L2-F/1080-1154-ND/2675645

Comment: I would try and get my design to use an available part if making a production, this is likely a popular part they have selected.  Be aware that some of these will have the elements in a vertical and some in a horizontal arrangement, it may be impossible to see from outside but testing should be able to determine.

Comment: it should be bottom of the spoke wheel.  The differential mode is more tolerant to stray IR light and aging of LED

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the one, though in the datasheet it's supposed to run off a 5V source. The mouse is powered by a couple of AAA batteries (3V max).

Comment: This one works from 1 to 20V easily